# AngularJS if-then-else construction with nested expressions

Tags: angularjs

I create dynamically a table and I want the two buttons in the last table cell of each row only if `x.deviceID==="-"` evaluates to false.

```
<tr class="contentRow" id="tableRow{{x.deviceID}}" ng-repeat="x in deviceData| filter:search">
  <td>{{x.deviceID}}</td>
  <td>{{x.otherID}}</td>
  <td>{{x.aaaa}}</td>
  <td>
    //this two buttons should only be there if x.deviceID==="-"
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>a
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>b
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My first approach was:

```
<td>{{x.deviceID}}</td>
<td>{{x.otherID}}</td>
<td>{{x.lastGpsDate}}</td>
<td>{{x.deviceID==="-" ? : '<button type"button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>a.....'}}
```

but this won't work. The last cell of the row will always look like this `{{x.deviceID==="---"? : '` BUTTON  BUTTON`'}}`. BUTTON is a real html button, not a string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-if` to solve the problem

```
<button ng-if="x.deviceID == '-'" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>a
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both inside a div and use `ng-if` or `ng-hide` to solve the problem

```
<tr class="contentRow" id="tableRow{{x.deviceID}}" ng-repeat="x in deviceData| filter:search">
  <td>{{x.deviceID}}</td>
  <td>{{x.otherID}}</td>
  <td>{{x.aaaa}}</td>
  <td>
      <div ng-if="x.deviceID === '-'">
          //this two buttons should only be there if x.deviceID==="-"
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>a
          </button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-deviceid="{{x.deviceID}}">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>b
          </button>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You could also use ng-hide with the same condition as well.
ng-if removes it from DOM & 
ng-hide just sets its display to false, but the buttons would still be in the DOM.